# Extract URL from IE using VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I think this is a little bit of an advance problem, I am fairly good with VBA, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this.

I would like to extract a URL from IE using VBA and assign this to a variable. This is only the first part of my problem... The idea is to open IE log into a website and then fill in forms on this website using Excel.

So my logic is to have this variable as an IE object and access the HTML behind the object and fill in the form using the properties of the IE object. But I don't really know how to start.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
THanks

Comment: Do you really need the URL of the site then? Or do you know the URL and are just trying to control IE via VBA?

Comment: I have just figured out how to make the link between IE through VBA, but now I want to populate a number of input fields of the IE object based on my spreadsheet

Comment: @Gareth This is basically what I have:

Dim ShellObj As Object  
Dim IEObj As Object  
Dim ActiveWindow As Object
Dim OpenPlease As Integer

OpenPlease = 0
Set ShellObj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each IEObj In ShellObj.Windows
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(IEObj.locationName, "Window To Work With", 1) > 0 Then
        Set ActiveWindow = IEObj
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Comment: I don't know how to paste the code nicely... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `getElementById` property to fill values and click buttons in Internet Explorer. Something like the below code should get you started:

```
Sub OpenIE()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.someaddress.com/login"

While IE.busy
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.getElementById("username").Value = "User"
IE.Document.getElementById("password").Value = "Password"
IE.Document.getElementById("RadioButton").Item(0).Checked = True
IE.Document.getElementById("submit").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how to set the property of a Yes/No field in IE?

Comment: :) Okay, logical I guess... Thanks again!

Comment: Hi sorry to bother again, but now I have given the website all of the values and it is copied in correctly into the page, but when I submit it does not want to submit the values as it is... It says "Go to your admin" but then if I just manually copy and paste the values from excel - it works perfectly when I submit the IE page Help plz :)